# Creating a loop using the randomForest() command

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, random-forest

so I have a vector of vectors called "formulas: that contains 31 potential models (1 output variable, and 5 potential explanatory variables).

```
$V1
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape"

$V2
[1] "Edible ~ CapSurface"

$V3
[1] "Edible ~ CapColor"

$V4
[1] "Edible ~ Odor"

$V5
[1] "Edible ~ Height"

$V6
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapSurface"

$V7
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapColor"

$V8
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + Odor"

$V9
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + Height"

$V10
[1] "Edible ~ CapSurface + CapColor"

$V11
[1] "Edible ~ CapSurface + Odor"

$V12
[1] "Edible ~ CapSurface + Height"

$V13
[1] "Edible ~ CapColor + Odor"

$V14
[1] "Edible ~ CapColor + Height"

$V15
[1] "Edible ~ Odor + Height"

$V16
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapSurface + CapColor"

$V17
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapSurface + Odor"

$V18
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapSurface + Height"

$V19
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapColor + Odor"

$V20
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapColor + Height"

$V21
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + Odor + Height"

$V22
[1] "Edible ~ CapSurface + CapColor + Odor"

$V23
[1] "Edible ~ CapSurface + CapColor + Height"

$V24
[1] "Edible ~ CapSurface + Odor + Height"

$V25
[1] "Edible ~ CapColor + Odor + Height"

$V26
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapSurface + CapColor + Odor"

$V27
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapSurface + CapColor + Height"

$V28
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapSurface + Odor + Height"

$V29
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapColor + Odor + Height"

$V30
[1] "Edible ~ CapSurface + CapColor + Odor + Height"

$V31
[1] "Edible ~ CapShape + CapSurface + CapColor + Odor + Height"
```

I'm trying to loop each model in the formulas vector through the randomForest() command, so I can generate 31 different random forest models, so far the loop I've tried to create is:

```
for (i in 1:length(formulas)){
current_model = randomForest(formula = formulas[i], data = mushrooms)
}
```

However, this keeps returning the error:

```
Error in nrow(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

The data "mushrooms" contain the variables that are in formulas as part of the column headings, I was wondering what I can do so that the randomForest() function identifies the models in formulas? For example, is there a way I convert this vector of vectors to a single vector and would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list` elements in `formulas` are strings.  We can convert them to `formula` class and it should work.  The `current_model` should be a `list` object for storing the model element instead of just reupdating  by same object on each iteration.  In the OP's code if it were to work, the 'current_model' returns only the last model

```
current_model <- vector('list', length(formulas))
for(i in seq_along(formulas)) {
 current_model[[i]] <-  randomForest(formula = as.formula(formulas[i]),
          data = mushrooms)

 }
```